# How to get any data from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, cpu-word

This is my first question on Here, but im trying my best!
So i making a code that get data from excel with DataGridView!

So for example, i got:

Name     Age     Item      Price     Day
John     23      phone     1000      21/12/2012

so im trying to print it to word using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
im just able to print the whole Grid, but i would like to print it like this:

Name: John, Age: 23 years old: item: phone, price is: $1000.00: Day of purchase: 21/12/2012

something like that! can anyone help me please, thank you so much and have a good day:!

so this is where im trying to print the DataGrid, in this case im printing the whole Grid, and it has to be in word.

```
          //Comienza la Tabla
        string tarjetas = "<table cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-size: 12pt;font-family:Courier-New'>";

        tarjetas += "<tr>";
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView3.Columns)
        {
            tarjetas += "<th style='background-color: #75cb84;border: 1px solid #ccc'>" + column.HeaderText + "</th>";
        }
        tarjetas += "</tr>";

        //estos son los datos de la tabla de Prestamos, de los Rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
        {
            tarjetas += "<tr>";
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                tarjetas += "<td style='width:160px;border: 1px solid #ccc'>" + cell.Value.ToString() + "</td>";
            }
            tarjetas += "</tr>";
        }

        //Termina la Tabla
        tarjetas += "</table>";

        //Save the HTML string as HTML File.
        string htmlFilePath = @"C:\DataGridView.htm";
        File.WriteAllText(htmlFilePath, tarjetas);

        //Convert the HTML File to Word document.
        _Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        _Document wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(FileName: htmlFilePath, ReadOnly: false);
        wordDoc.SaveAs(FileName: @"C:\ListadoTarjetas.doc", FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);
        ((_Document)wordDoc).Close();
        ((_Application)word).Quit();

        //Delete the HTML File.
        File.Delete(htmlFilePath);

        MessageBox.Show("Reporte Generado con exito!");
```

Comment: Use DataBinding where the data never actually goes ***in*** the control and there is no issue with fishing it out.  NET has print capabilities as well, so there is no need to send data to Word for printing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some of your code, so we can see what attempts you have made so far.

Comment: i just edit the post! so you can check what i am printing

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Why are you writing the data from the grid to an “htm” file? When you open that file in Word, its going to put the data into a “table” which you can format any way you want. If you do not want the data in a table, then you could write the data “directly” into the Word document. I recommend a method that takes a row index from the grid and returns a formatted string as you want, then use that in a loop through the grids rows and write each string to a new paragraph in the Word document.